# Liquibase db update fails saying DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK is already an existing object

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to log in as user account and create synonyms for all objects available in owner account, using liquibase changeset. I am getting below error when running the liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.

```
liquibase: Executing EXECUTE database command: CREATE TABLE SSEAPSL_USER_01.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, LOCKED NUMBER(1) NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR2(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID))
Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
SEVERE 20/07/15 12:39: liquibase: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
        at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.acquireLock(StandardLockService.java:215)
```

But the user account doesn't have `DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK` table created. Only Owner account has that table. Please could someone help me how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When using Oracle, if you use user credentials in your liquibase connection, the schema that Liquibase will want to use is the schema ***for that user***. You should be able to work around this by specifying the name of the schema you actually want to manage (the owner schema).

You didn't specify, but it looks like you might be using the command line to run Liquibase. If that is the case, you can specify `--defaultSchemaName=ownerschema` on the command line.

http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html